# Is it possible to change themes per category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is it possible to change the WordPress theme based on a category?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress [supports per-category themes out-of-the-box in a couple different ways](http://technosailor.com/2007/03/31/wordpress-faq-how-do-i-use-category-themes/).